# MySQL getting overwhelmed after restart after an apparent crash

Tags: mysql

I found my site dead this morning, with every request timing out.  `systemctl restart nginx` made no difference - but `systemctl restart mysql` did.

Last night I set a long-running `UPDATE` query running.  I suspect 10 hours in this is what killed mysql.

But now my server which typically has a load average of 1-2 (with 32 cores) keeps hitting 20+.  `show processlist` shows a lot of `creating sort index` on a popular complex query on the site, but it's never been a problem before.  Eventually the site stops responding, and I have to restart mysql again.

I've run repair/optimise on all tables involved in the `UPDATE` query.  What else could be going on?

Comment: Sounds like you are using ENGINE=MyISAM.  Switch to InnoDB to avoid the need for repair.  Furthermore, if a MyISAM Update is interrupted in the middle, there is no way to "pick up where it left off".

Comment: I'm not, InnoDB tables throughout.

Comment: It does seem to me like it IS trying to continue the UPDATE whenever I restart mysql, given how much the server is struggling - but the query doesn't show in the processlist, so I assume it's NOT doing that?

Comment: I don't know if either of these things are significant:  1) I'm actually using MariaDB, not MySQL.   2) I only have ib_logfile0 - ib_logfile1 doesn't exist.

Comment: A bit of me wants to do a clean shutdown and then move ib_logfile0 to somewhere else (not delete, in case it turns out I need it!) and then start the DB, but I don't know if that'll cause bigger problems?

Comment: If you are using InnoDB...  The restart would be `ROLLBACKing` the Update.  This is a costly operation.  After it finishes, you would need to rerun the Update (or avoid the Update somehow)

Comment: Usually a "huge" Update is a result of a poorly designed schema or data-flow.  Please describe what it is doing; we can discuss alternatives.  Here's one possibility:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  (It applies to Updates, too.)

Comment: It was a one-off update due to a bug that had led to some data inconsistencies.  I've now batched it into a sequence of smaller updates via cron, all sorted 

Comment: Sorted on the PK, I hope.  And not using OFFSET, I hope.

Comment: Nothing that simple; multiple joins, and a subquery with multiple joins and aggregates in.  But, all sorted now.

Comment: Now that you have stabilized, Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide busy survival suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck:

EPYC 7502, 32cr/64th, 128GB, system and DB on NVME drives.  Box is both my web and my DB server.  Website also hosted from NVME, and have additional SATA drives for asset storage.

Output of those commands:  https://justpaste.it/a1rh5

I should note that "STATUS" didn't work - maybe because this is MariaDB and you thought I was on MySQL?

Thank you!  I'm a full-stack self-taught dev with a project that has grown beyond what I ever anticipated.  It doesn't make a huge amount of money, but the community love it so I keep plugging away.  ANY insights appreciated!

Comment: @Codemonkey  Analysis in process.  Is it possible  from MySQL command prompt, STATUS;  then press Enter  would produce a quick summary?

Comment: Right you are, I've added it to the bottom of the earlier justpaste link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you kill mysqld, with SIGKILL, or there is a crash during a long uncommitted transaction, then, at startup, mysql will rollback that transaction. Each query is by default wrapped in a transaction if you are using InnoDB.

I suggest to let it complete the rollback.

You can monitor the status with:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND <> 'Sleep' and TIME > 1 ;
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
```

Comment: Empty result set.  I didn't kill mysqld in an unpleasant way, I just issued `systemctl restart mysql` which I think does a graceful shutodwn.  As far as I know it's doing no rollback, in fact my CPU usage is essentially 0 while the webserver is offline.  About 5 minutes after starting the webserver back up the DB becomes overwhelmed.

I feel there must be a corrupted file (are there any tools to look for this?) or some indexes got deleted along the way (they certainly weren't by me, or by my code).  ‍♂️

Comment: I tried setting innodb_fast_shutdown=0 and then stopping mysql, and it managed to stop within a couple of seconds.  I've run out of ideas and am rebooting the machine now... that it makes a difference

Comment: It has not. 

Comment: Could you add the output of those 2 queries to the question? Replace any sensitive data with `****`

Comment: Sure.  When the server is overwhelmed, or when it's idling, before I enable the webserver?

Comment: I think it might be a "thundering herd" scenario, because the website has been offline for a while.  I've tried a soft-reopening, by allowing just 10% of IP addresses to access the site, then 20%|, then 50%, 75% and finally 100% and I think maybe the problem has resolved itself.  Maybe.

Comment: Best way to run those 2 queries is when the site is slow and you suspect it's the DB the bottleneck.

Comment: If it happens again, I will.  For now, all seems good...

But I do need to work on some graceful degradation, as the site shouldn't simply fall over if the load gets too high.

Comment: @Codemonkey - a simpler way is to set `max_connections` to a smaller number and leave it there.  40 might be good.  When hundreds of connections are made, MySQL gives each a fair chance at the CPU (etc).  This leads to _all_ connections taking a long time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

codemonkey,

Your max_used_connections was 98 for your 7 days of uptime reflected in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.  It might be reasonable to lower max_connections from 500 to 256 since your site is popular.

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of your available NVME IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=16K  # from 4M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 36,095
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.00001  # from 0 percent to ENABLE pre-flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.00001  # from 90 percent to clear innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty faster. You had 194,905 dirty pages when SGS recorded.  A very large number of dirty pages to keep up with on your server.
```

There are many more opportunities to improve your configuration for better performance.  View profile, please.